# How can I relate two ids when they have both the same definition in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have this conceptual problem:

```
id=1 => id=2
id=2 => id=null
id=3 => id=2
id=4 => id=3
```

How can I relate these two ids in XSLT?

Comment: It sounds like some mapping, in XSLT 3.0 with maps and XPath 3.1 you can define e.g. `<xsl:param name="id-map" select="map { 1 : 2, 2 : (), 3 : 2, 4 : 3 }"/>` and e.g. `$id-map(3)` gives `2`.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please show your XML input and your desired XML output, and explain how the output depends on the input.

Comment: Hi! I already was able to solve this problem and I just don't post the answer because it's very specific to Spinque.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was built in Spinque. The way I solved it was creating two variables that had the same URI and just changed the number of the id. Then I related them with a spinque relation.

```
<xsl:variable name="recnrootNR" select="su:uri('https://syngenta.com/data/specification/',su:toNumber(field[@name='RECNROOT_SRC']))"/>
<xsl:variable name="recnrootCM" select="su:uri('https://syngenta.com/data/specification/',su:toNumber(field[@name='RECNROOT_DST']))"/>
<spinque:relation subject="{$recnrootNR}" predicate="rdfs:Component" object="{$recnrootCM}" />
```